# How can I create a color registration test page with latex?

Tags: color

For color registration there is the special color [*registration black*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registration_black), which uses 100% of all colors used in print. This way misalignment can be easily spotted:

[image]

How can I create a color registration test page to test my printer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`colorspace`](https://ctan.org/pkg/colorspace?lang=de) package provides support for spot colors. This includes the special color `All`. This way we can create a calibration sheet (the crosses use the special registration color):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{colorspace}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\definespotcolor{registration}{All}{1,1,1,1}

\newcommand{\cbox}[1]{\tikz \fill [#1] (0.0,0.0) rectangle (0.5,0.5);}
\newcommand{\cmyktest}{\cbox{cyan} \cbox{magenta} \cbox{yellow} \cbox{black} \cbox{magenta!50!cyan} \cbox{yellow!50!cyan} \cbox{black!50!cyan} \cbox{yellow!50!magenta} \cbox{black!50!magenta} \cbox{black!50!yellow}}
\newcommand{\rmark}{(0,0) -- (2,0) (1,1) -- (1,-1) (.5,0) arc (0:360:-.5)}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\centering\cmyktest

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, draw=registration, ultra thin]
    \draw[shift={($(current page.north west)+(1,-2)$)}] \rmark;
    \draw[shift={($(current page.north east)+(-3,-2)$)}] \rmark;
    \draw[shift={($(current page.south west)+(1,2)$)}] \rmark;
    \draw[shift={($(current page.south east)+(-3,2)$)}] \rmark;
\end{tikzpicture}

\vfill\cmyktest
\end{document}
```

[image: color calibration page]

Comment: I get this error message: `17: Undefined control sequence.  \color@&spot ...->\c@lor@arg {#2}\edef #1{\spc@ir \space cs \spc@ir \space C...`  I’m using an up-to-date TeX Live 2018, and the error occurs with both pdflatex and lualatex.

Comment: I updated my packages and now it is also broken. Not sure why. Maybe this would be good for a new question.

Comment: I've released a new version of `colorspace`.

Comment: Great! I hope MiKTeX updates their package soon.

Comment: @JavierBezos I just tried and it seems like the registration color (defined by `\definespotcolor{registration}{All}{1,1,1,1}`) isn't showing in my pdf viewer.

Comment: If I set in the preamble `\color{registration]` (ie, globally) they are shown. So I presume the problem is the way the marks are defined.

Comment: @JavierBezos I don't think so. This MWE is also broken for me: https://pastebin.com/ht14WSga

Comment: @someonr If I surround the conflicting line with `{\color{registration}...}` it's shown. I don't know why `draw=registration` doesn't and I must investigate.